# how to return value inside of forEach loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I got stuck with my code.

I wrote this sample code only for the purpose to reproduce my problem, so this code is not practical at all but I hope you get my point.

In the code below, for the last value to be output, I expect it to be 3, but it's undefined.

How am I supposed to write if I want the last value to be 3 in this case??

This is just a sample code, but in the actual code, I fetch content from amazon api and when it returns api error, I want to run the same function again after 1000 milli seconds.

```
var list = [1,2,3];
var someClass = new SomeClass();

list.forEach(function(value) {

    var result = someClass.getSomething(value);

    console.log("outside: " + result);  

});


function SomeClass() {

    var flag = false;

    this.getSomething = function(something) {

        if (something === 3 && flag === false) {

            flag = true;
            this.getSomething(something);

            //I need to return here, so the succeeding code is not read.
            return;

        }

        console.log("inside: " + String(something));

        return something;

    }

}
```

**Log**

```
inside: 1
outside: 1
inside: 2
outside: 2
inside: 3
outside: undefined // I expect this value to be 3!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
function SomeClass() {

    var flag = false;

    this.getSomething = function(something) {

        if (something === 3 && flag === false) {

            flag = true;

            this.getSomething(something); // not returning this

            return; // returning undefined

        }

        console.log("inside: " + String(something));

        return something;

    }

}
```

Here's the fix:

```
function SomeClass() {

    var flag = false;

    this.getSomething = function(something) {

        if (something === 3 && flag === false) {

            flag = true;

            return this.getSomething(something);

        }

        console.log("inside: " + String(something));

        return something;

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes!! This is what I want!! Thank you so much!! I need to wait for a few more minutes to accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have a test:

> ```
>    if (something === 3 && flag === false) {
>        //...
>        return;
> ```

If you want to return `3` then don't have a `return` statement with nothing after it. `return` means `return undefined`. Put `return 3` or `return something`.

You probably want to return from your recursive call though:

```
return this.getSomething(something);
```

Comment: In his code, he has a call for the same function inside the function itself `this.getSomething(something)' what is the behavior for this? Im just curious. It is like recursive or infinite

Comment: Yes, it's recursive!  In the actual code, I fetch content from amazon api and when it returns api error, I want to run the same function again after 1000 milli seconds.

Answer (score 0):

change the code to

if (something === 3 && flag === false)
 {

```
       flag = true;
        return this.getSomething(something);
```

}

"return;" returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

It returns `undefined` in your code because you `return;` in the `if` clause.

`return this.getSomething(something)` within the `if` clause

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var someClass = new SomeClass();

list.forEach(function(value) {

    var result = someClass.getSomething(value);

    console.log("outside: " + result);

});


function SomeClass() {

    var flag = false;

    this.getSomething = function(something) {

        if (something === 3 && flag === false) {

            flag = true;
            return this.getSomething(something);

        }

        console.log("inside: " + String(something));

        return something;

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

forEach loop doesn't return a value.
You can create a global variable and assign values to it.

Comment: While this is true, it isn't actually relevant to the problem. The code in the question doesn't try to return a value from `forEach`.